# linq query with different entitiesmodel

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually i have two tableA, tableB i have records in tableA.
TanleA is related to one entity and TableB is related to another entitymodel
If i have the same related records in tableB then i shoulds display TRUE if records are not inserted in tableB it should display FALSE. Finally i should display all records in grid display so please tell me in which way i can proceed. PLease send me sample code...

i have written inthis way but it's getting null exception

```
var que = (from i in ContactsContext.My_schedule_categories
                         join j in profileContexton i.Usr_schedule_category_id equals j.sid into g
                        from j in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where i.catid == j.Usr_contact_schedule_setting_cat_ID
                        select new
                       {

                           category = i.Usr_schedule_category,
                           catid = i.Usr_schedule_category_id,
                           ownerid = i.Usr_schedule_owner_usr_id,
                           sid = j.sid

                       }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unreadable as is your question. However I can make few assumptions and suggest an answer:

- Entity Framework doesn't support JOINs on different contexts (`ContactsContext` and `profileContext`). See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7a6093d7-c7ea-43ce-bd01-19c4b1fba724 for details.
- Your use of `DefaultIfEmpty` is incorrect. See [DefaultIfEmpty in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854181/defaultifempty-in-linq) for details.